# An identity for holomorphic functional calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, $p\in A$ a projection, and $a\in A$ self-adjoint. Let $\Gamma$ be the circle of radius $1/2$ with center $1$. It is claimed that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma(z-p)^{-1}a(z-p)^{-1}\,dz=pa(1-p)+(1-p)ap.$$

I'm looking for a hint to prove this.

*Comment:* I understand that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma(z-p)^{-1}\,dz=p,$$
hence $pa(1-p)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\frac{a(1-p)}{z-p}\,dz$ and $(1-p)ap=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\frac{(1-p)a}{z-p}\,dz$. So
$$pa(1-p)+(1-p)ap=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\frac{a(1-p)(z-p)+(1-p)a(z-p)}{(z-p)^2}\,dz.$$
But I'm not sure if this is the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since things do not commute, you have to be careful as the expressions in your integrals are ambiguous when you write a quotient.*

You have, for $z\not \in\{0,1\}$,
$$
(z-p)^{-1}=\frac1z\,(1-p)-\frac1{1-z}\,p.
$$
Now you can compute $(z-p)^{-1}a(z-p)^{-1}$ and integrate, using that the curve encloses $1$ and not $0$,

Comment: Hmm interesting. So if $\Gamma$ is a curve that encloses $0$ instead of $1$, then you'd just get the negative of this answer. I wonder if there's any meaningful interpretation of this...

Comment: There is likely something, but I couldn't tell.